# Why does my database crash after adding a new column?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am trying to add a new column into an `SQLiteDatabase` but every time I try to run the code with the new column it crashes. If I simply add the new column then it runs alright but when I try to use it in code it crashes. The value in question is `KEY_END_TIME` and any value with the word "end" in it. I tried passing it the same exact values as `KEY_DATE_TIME`, more or less using them in the exact same context in an attempt to get it running but it immediately crashes every time. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
/**
 * Simple reminder database access helper class. 
 * Defines the basic CRUD operations (Create, Read, Update, Delete)
 * for the example, and gives the ability to list all reminders as well as
 * retrieve or modify a specific reminder.
 * 
 */
public class RemindersDbAdapter {

//
// Databsae Related Constants
//
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "reminders";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;

public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_CUSTOMER = "body";
public static final String KEY_DATE_TIME = "reminder_date_time"; 
public static final String KEY_END_TIME = "reminder_end_time"; 
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";


private static final String TAG = "ReminderDbAdapter";
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

/**
 * Database creation SQL statement
 */
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
                + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + KEY_TITLE + " text not null, " 
                + KEY_CUSTOMER + " text not null, " 
                + KEY_DATE_TIME + " text not null);"
                + KEY_END_TIME + " text not null);"; 



private final Context mCtx;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

/**
 * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
 * opened/created
 * 
 * @param ctx the Context within which to work
 */
public RemindersDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

/**
 * Open the database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
 * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
 * signal the failure
 * 
 * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
 *         initialization call)
 * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
 */
public RemindersDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
}


/**
 * Create a new reminder using the title, body and reminder date time provided. 
 * If the reminder is  successfully created return the new rowId
 * for that reminder, otherwise return a -1 to indicate failure.
 * 
 * @param title the title of the reminder
 * @param body the body of the reminder
 * @param reminderDateTime the date and time the reminder should remind the user
 * @return rowId or -1 if failed
 */
public long createReminder(String title, String body, String reminderDateTime, String        reminderEndTime) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(KEY_CUSTOMER, body);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, reminderDateTime);
    initialValues.put(KEY_END_TIME, reminderDateTime); 

    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

/**
 * Delete the reminder with the given rowId
 * 
 * @param rowId id of reminder to delete
 * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
 */
public boolean deleteReminder(long rowId) {

    return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

/**
 * Return a Cursor over the list of all reminders in the database
 * 
 * @return Cursor over all reminders
 */
public Cursor fetchAllReminders() {

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_CUSTOMER, KEY_DATE_TIME, KEY_END_TIME}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

/**
 * Return a Cursor positioned at the reminder that matches the given rowId
 * 
 * @param rowId id of reminder to retrieve
 * @return Cursor positioned to matching reminder, if found
 * @throws SQLException if reminder could not be found/retrieved
 */
public Cursor fetchReminder(long rowId) throws SQLException {

    Cursor mCursor =

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_TITLE, KEY_CUSTOMER, KEY_DATE_TIME, KEY_END_TIME}, KEY_ROWID +     "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}

/**
 * Update the reminder using the details provided. The reminder to be updated is
 * specified using the rowId, and it is altered to use the title, body and reminder     date time
 * values passed in
 * 
 * @param rowId id of reminder to update
 * @param title value to set reminder title to
 * @param body value to set reminder body to
 * @param reminderDateTime value to set the reminder time. 
 * @return true if the reminder was successfully updated, false otherwise
 */
public boolean updateReminder(long rowId, String title, String body, String reminderDateTime, String reminderEndTime) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    args.put(KEY_CUSTOMER, body);
    args.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, reminderDateTime);
    args.put(KEY_END_TIME, reminderEndTime);

    return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

}

```
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dummies.android.TaskReminder/com.dummies.android.TaskReminder.TaskReminderActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: reminder_end_time: , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, body, reminder_date_time, reminder_end_time FROM reminders
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: reminder_end_time: , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, body, reminder_date_time, reminder_end_time FROM reminders
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1449)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1405)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1485)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.dummies.android.TaskReminder.RemindersDbAdapter.fetchAllReminders(RemindersDbAdapter.java:144)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.dummies.android.TaskReminder.TaskReminderActivity.fillData(TaskReminderActivity.java:40)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.dummies.android.TaskReminder.TaskReminderActivity.onCreate(TaskReminderActivity.java:33)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-15 18:11:12.356: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
```

Comment: have you increased the DATABASE_VERSION?

Comment: If you've already created the database and table once, the `onCreate(...)` method of `SQLiteOpenHelper` won't be run again. Are you making sure you've incremented the database version number to ensure `onUpgrade()` is run?

Comment: Yes, unless I am doing wrong, all you do is change DATABASE_VERSION from 3 to 4 right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sql creation string is wrong. Modify it like this:

```
...+ KEY_DATE_TIME + " text not null, "
                + KEY_END_TIME + " text not null);";
```

Remember to uninstall and then reinstall your app so the `onCreate` method is called again and the database recreated.

Comment: Its such a dumb mistake in hindsight haha. Thanks for the help, this site is a real life saver!

Answer (score 1):

I think issue in

```
"create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
        + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + KEY_TITLE + " text not null, " 
        + KEY_CUSTOMER + " text not null, " 
        + KEY_DATE_TIME + " text not null);"
        + KEY_END_TIME + " text not null);";
```

");" get twice

Comment: You might be right, but is there a specific way to update it? Am I updating it wrong if I just change the 
DATABASE_VERSION = 4; to DATABASE_VERSION = 5; ?

Answer (score 1):

Your create statement is mal-formed:

```
 + KEY_DATE_TIME + " text not null);"
            + KEY_END_TIME + " text not null);";
```

You have the closing ");" twice so the line to add the KEY_END_TIME is outside of the create statement and isn't executed.